# Efficiently applying custom function to pandas DataFrame groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I am working with a large pandas DataFrame (over 1M rows) that I need to group by one column, and then apply a custom function to each group. The DataFrame df has the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Category  Value
0        A     10
1        B     20
2        A     30
3        B     40
4        A     50
5        A     60
6        B     70
7        B     80
```

My custom function calculates the sum of squares of the 'Value' for each 'Category'. Here's the function:

```
def sum_of_squares(group):
    return (group**2).sum()
```

Currently, I'm applying this function to each group like so:

```
df.groupby('Category')['Value'].apply(sum_of_squares)
```

But as the DataFrame is very large, this operation takes quite a while to complete. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this, especially when working with large DataFrames.

Would appreciate any guidance on this. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested `df.groupby('Category')['Value'].agg(sum_of_squares)`?

Comment: I would recommend `(1)` df['val2'] = df['val'] * df['val'], then `(2)` df.groupby('Category')['val2'].sum(). There is no need for a custom function here

Answer (score 2):

Replace slow `apply` approach with chained [`pow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pow.html)ering (on `Value`) + `sum` operations (on groups):

```
df['Value'].pow(2).groupby(df['Category']).sum()
```

---

Though the input dataset is quite small, here's an approximate time performance difference:

```
In [55]: %timeit df.groupby('Category')['Value'].apply(sum_of_squares)
612 µs ± 3.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [56]: %timeit df['Value'].pow(2).groupby(df['Category']).sum()
373 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For the same result:

```
Category
A     7100
B    13300
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hehe we thought of the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

There could be many bottlenecks in here, so it's hard to know without looking at the actual `df`

First, since `group ** 2` in a vectorizable operation, definitely do it at the data frame level, rather than the group level.

Second, `groupby` works slower with some data structures, and faster with others. Try different data structures. `string` is usually a very slow one, especially if you have long strings. Other data structures are even slower (like tuples etc.).

One idea is to use `pd.factorize` to get integers rather than strings, which are more quicker to group by, and only map back to strings at the end, with a small, aggregated data frame.

This would mean doing

```
cats , mapper = pd.factorize(df['Category'])
```

And then

```
(df['Value'] ** 2).groupby(cats).sum()
```

This works very well if the main bottleneck is the string matching in `groupby`, or if you do many groupby operations throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many groups, the groupby operation might be the bottleneck.

That said, `apply` is not the most optimized method, you could try:

```
df['Value'].pow(2).groupby(df['Category']).sum()
```